# ios - No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I get this error:

```
No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates
```

and part of the problem is that my bundle id is incorrect. But when I try to edit it in xCode, it is grayed out (uneditable).

So I tried to edit it in the Project -> info screen, but in my case I didn't have anything there.

I also edited it in the .plist file, but that didn't make any impact.

[image]

Would anyone please be able to help me resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **Targets->Summary->BundleIdentifier** instead of **Project->Info**

The last section of  Bundle Identifier(which refers ur app name) may not be editable.

However you can edit the first two sections of Bundle Identifier (e.g. com.domainname will be editable )

Point your cursor position at the end of **Bundle Identifier** (at the end of `com.domainname`. That means 'e') and use **delete** key to **clear** and **modify** it.

Im my screen shot, you can see the `com-Dev.test` is **editable** and **enabled**.

[image]

Comment: right, but the bundle id there is not editable. It is grayed out. That is my problem. :(

Comment: Yes exactly, you see how for you, the last part is in gray color? I have that too and I need to change it to match the bundle id I created.

Comment: So if my project name is not editable, and my bundle id is already made in apples provisioning portal, should I just re-create the bundle id in the provisioning portal?

Comment: Sorry I got confused. Where can I do this? in xCode or in the ios provisioning portal?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it now. This is making sense. Let me try it...brb in 1 min with results :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26757/discussion-between-genadinik-and-ramshad)